# Ruby Regex Rubular vs reality

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

I have a string and I want to remove all non-word characters and whitespace from it. So I thought Regular expressions would be what I need for that.

My Regex looks like that (I defined it in the string class as a method):

```
/[\w&&\S]+/.match(self.downcase)
```

when I run this expression in Rubular with the test string `"hello ..a.sdf asdf..,"` it highlioghts all the stuff I need ("hellloasdfasdf") but when I do the same in irb I only get "hello".

Has anyone any ideas about why that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use `match`, with returns one matching element. If you use `scan` instead, all should work properly:

```
string = "hello ..a.sdf asdf..,"
string.downcase.scan(/[\w&&\S]+/)
# => ["hello", "a", "sdf", "asdf"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a built in function to convert that array into one string?

Comment: Allright, I found it out myself. For reference: Use the join method.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` means [a-zA-Z0-9_]

`\S` means any non-whitespace character `[a-zA-Z_-0-9!@#$%^&*\(\)\\{}?><....etc]`

so using  a `\w` `and` `\S` condition is ambiguous.

Its like saying `What is an intersection of India and Asia`. Obviously its going to be India. So I will suggest you to use `\w+`.

and you can use scan to get all matches as mentioned in the second answer :

```
string = "hello ..a.sdf asdf..,"
string.scan(/\w+/)
```